# Assemble directed root tree from edges without exploding memory?

Tags: scala, data-structures, tail-recursion

Given a list of edges (parent <--> child), how can I assemble the implied directed rooted tree (1 parent for any child, unlimited children for any parent) in a recursive data structure (`class Node(name: String, children: Array[Node])`) without risking the stack overflow error that comes with simple recursion?

Bonus in Scala:

```
def constructTree(root: String, parentToChild: Map[String, String]): Node = ???

case class Node(name: String, children: Seq[Node])
```

Comment: So what is the question

Comment: you can either implement the method above, "constructTree(root, parentToChild)", or give a more pseudo code answer to the question above?  either would be helpful!

Comment: If the parent-to-child relationship is one-to-many then the `parentToChild` Map should either be `Map[String, List[String]]` (parent as key, zero or more children), or `Map[String, String]` (child as key used to look up the parent). Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I barely know Scala, but this is a pretty language-agnostic question.

First, your `parentToChild` data structure doesn't make sense unless each node can have only one child. Unlikely. You probably want a `MultiMap`.

The algorithm is pretty simple: Make a first pass through the `parentToChild` multimap just to build a new map `Name -> Node` where the lists of children in all nodes are empty. Then make a second pass through `parentToChild` and use your new map to add the child pointers.

I can't see why you'd think recursion would play a part.  This is simple iteration.

Here's pseudocode:

```
set nameToNode = \empty
for each entry (parentName, childName) in parentToChild
  nameToNode.addIfNotPresent(parentName, new Node(parentName))
  nameToNode.addIfNotPresent(childName, new Node(childName))

for each entry (parentName, childName) in parentToChild
  set parent = nameToNode.get(parentName)
  set child = nameToNode.get(childName)
  parent.chilren.add(child)
```

If you don't already know the root node(s), then add this:

```
set roots = \empty
set nodeToHasInwardEdge = \empty
for each entry (name, node) in nameToNode // name is ignored
  for each child in node.children
    nodeToHasInwardEdge.put(child, true)
for each entry (name, node) in nameToNode // name is ignored
  if nodeToHasInwardEdge.get(node) == null
    roots.add(node)
```

Actually you can merge the first loop above with the second one in the previous snippet, so only 3 passes are required to add all edges and find all roots.  Even if you *think* you know the root, it would be wise to use this as a check. Just verify there's exactly one root.  Similarly if the input is supposed to represent a tree, you can use an integer count instead of a boolean above and verify each non-root node has exactly one in-edge.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding: I'm not seeing how you "make a second pass through" to build out a single tree structure.  Given my understanding of your answer, I'd be left with many 1 level deep trees.  My challenge is consolidating them all into one tree, which I'm not understanding from your answer.  To do this you COULD start with the root, find the children, go through each child, find it's children, etc, but that is the recursive approach that can run into stack overflow problems with a sufficiently large tree.  Maybe if you shared some pseudo code that might help me understand?

Comment: your solution works with mutable data structures.  i don't believe it works with immutable data structures.  while scala favors an immutable approach, i didn't specify that in my question, so now i understand where you're coming from.  immutability would be ideal!  thanks for helping out

Comment: @MatthewSlotkin Entire PhD theses and books have been devoted to graph algorithms implemented in purely functional style over immutable store. They're almost always more complicated and less efficient than imperative algorithms using assignment. For practical purposes, the only reasonable approach is to build with mutable objects as I've shown. That's why Scala has mutable containers in addition to the immutable ones. You can convert the graph to an immutable one in a final pass if that's what the application requires.